# Converging sequence and its limit

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the sequence $x_n$ given by

$$x_0=0, x_1=1 \ \ \text{ and} \ \  x_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}x^{2}_{n}+\frac{3}{4}x^{2}_{n-1}}$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$

converges and find its limit.

My progress so far:
This is an intertwining sequence, and I am trying to show $I_{n+1}\subseteq I_n$ where interval $I_{n+1}=[x_{n}, x_{n-1}]$ by mathematical induction, but I failed to prove that case $n+1$ is true given that case $n$ is true. And I have no idea with the steps thereafter.

Comment: What's an "intertwining sequence"?

Comment: why should the order $x_n <x_{n-1}$ hold? Note that $x_2=1/2$ and $x_3 =\sqrt{13/16}>1/2$. Another idea: a subsequence converges since the sequence is bounded. This gives the limit. To show that the whole sequence converges, you can show that every subequence converges to the same limit (this is a lemma by Cauchy)

Comment: It converges to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly
$x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2=-\frac{3}{4}(x_n^2-x_{n-1}^2)$ and hence $x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2=(-\frac{3}{4})^n$. Thus
$$ x_{n+1}^2=\sum_{k=0}^n(x_{k+1}^2-x_k^2)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-\frac{3}{4})^n\to \frac{1}{1-(-\frac34)}=\frac{4}{7} $$
and hence
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\frac{2}{\sqrt 7}. $$

Answer (score 1):

The square root is making this difficult.  Let's square both sides of your recursive expression:

$$x_{n+1}^2 = \frac{1}{4}x_n^2 + \frac{3}{4}x_{n-1}^2$$

let's consider the sequence $(y_n) = (x_n^2)$.  Since each term in $(x_n)$ is nonnegative (by virtue of the square root), we have that $(x_n) = (\sqrt{y_n})$, so if $(y_n)$ converges to $y$, then $(x_n)$ will converge to $\sqrt{y}$.

We now have the linear recurrence relation

$$y_{n+1} = \frac{1}{4}y_n + \frac{3}{4}y_{n-1}$$

which we can rewrite in matrix form as
$$\left[\begin{array}{c} y_{n+1} \\ y_n\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c} y_{n} \\ y_{n-1}\end{array}\right]$$

so

$$\left[\begin{array}{c} y_{n+1} \\ y_n\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right]^n \left[\begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_0\end{array}\right]$$

If find that the eigenvectors of the matrix are $\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\end{array}\right]^T$ and $\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -\frac{4}{3}\end{array}\right]^T$, with eigenvalues of $1$ and $-\frac{3}{4}$, respectively.  Thus, if we could write
$$\left[\begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_0\end{array}\right] = a \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1\end{array}\right] + b \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ -\frac{4}{3}\end{array}\right]$$

Then we would have

$$\left[\begin{array}{c} y_{n+1} \\ y_n\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4}\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right]^n \left[\begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_0\end{array}\right] = a(1)^n \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1\end{array}\right] + b\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^n \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ -\frac{4}{3}\end{array}\right]$$

as $n\to\infty$, the second term vanishes, so we would have $(y_n) \to a$, and thus $(x_n) \to \sqrt{a}$.  I'll leave it to you to fill in the details.

Comment: @DanielV Indeed it should.  Edited.